# Using Eval Boolean to set a style for an asp.net control

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, eval, conditional-statements

I have an `asp:ListView` control containing a bunch of images set up like this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvSliderPhotos" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="imgSliderPhoto" runat="server"
            ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ThumbnailPath") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

For my DB table containing these I have a field called `IsPublic` which stores a boolean.  How can I apply a style to the `asp:Image` control if the value is false?

I basically want something like this:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgSliderPhoto" runat="server"
    ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ThumbnailPath") %>'
    Style='<if (!Eval("IsPublic") { set a style property }>' />
```

Any idea how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the value of `IsPublic` inside the `CssClass` property of the image control and set it to the desired style rule:

```
CssClass='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsPublic")) ? "public" : "private" %>'
```

**Complete example:**

```
  <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .public {
            border: 6px solid red;
        }

        .private {
            border: 6px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListView ID="lvSliderPhotos" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="imgSliderPhoto" runat="server"
                    ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ThumbnailPath") %>' CssClass='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsPublic")) ? "public" : "private" %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </form>
</body>
```